# How to remove decimal point in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, integer

I want to remove decimal point from value in jquery.

I have this:

> 48.00

and I want it to change

> 4800

in jquery, javascript, regex or php.

Thanks

Comment: *in jquery, javascript, regex or php* - those are 4 entirely different things..

Comment: Math.round(48.00* 1000) / 10;

Comment: Hello Bizzon your answer is right

Answer (score 0):

For PHP use `str_replace('.', '', $string)`

For Javascript use `var str = "20.01"; str.replace(".","");`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery/Javascript:

```
value = value.replace(".", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`num = 48.00;`
`num.toString().replace('.', '');`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) (round down), [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) (round up) or [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) (round to nearest integer), dependent on how you wanted to remove the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.round(48.00* 1000) / 10;
```

Credit goes to

> Bizzon